# SolrCore Initialization Failures: trouble reloading core

Tags: python, django, solr, solrconfig

Somebody help.

I am getting

"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core account: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType. Schema file is solr/account\conf\schema.xml"

when I try to reload my core. Dont know what the problem is.

I am using solr 4.10.4.

Here is my solrconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_36</luceneMatchVersion>
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler"
default="true" />
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
<requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
<lst name="invariants">
  <str name="qt">search</str>
  <str name="q">*:*</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
</config>
```

thanks

Comment: Theres is some issue with the schema. Post that file here. Also, I don't think your lucene match version is correct since you're using 4.x

Comment: @BinoyDalal [`LUCENE_36` is deprecated in version 4.x](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html#LUCENE_36) (but supported)

Answer (score 0):

First check that `schema.xml` is present in path (as stated by your exception).

Then I suggest to correct your `solr/account\conf\schema.xml` path changing your `\` backslashes into `/` slashes.

To be clear, you should write:

```
solr/account/conf/schema.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a chance that you are running solrCloud, see the `-c` arg

```
./solr start -c -m 1g
```

use this instead

```
./solr start -m 1g
```